# Kirchoff's Law Loop Equation Problem

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws, homework

This is the question I am struggling with
[image]

I have found a node equation:

$$ I_3 = I_1 + I_2 $$

I have found two loop equations:

$$ 50 = I_3 + R_1 \times I_1 $$

$$ 50 = I_3 + R_2 \times I_2 $$

I'm not sure what the third loop equation is.

Answer (score 1):

Your two loop equations are incorrect. I3 should not appear in either equation.  For one, the units don't match: I3 is a current while R1*I1 and R2*R2 are voltages.Since your have 3 unknowns and 3 equations, a third loop equation is unnecessary. You could create a third loop equation using the loop around R1 and R2 but it does not yield any additional information about the unknown quantities: I1, I2 and I3.

Comment: In that case, what would the loop equations be? I'm totally lost

Comment: So two of them would be: 50 = I2R2 and 50 = I1R1?

Comment: Yep @Spartasporter

Comment: What would the third loop equation be then?

Comment: @Spartasporter You should read what Barry has written. "*You could create a third loo...*".

Comment: So would the third equation be I1R1+I2R2=50?

Comment: I also have to use an augmented matrix to find the values of I1,I2,I3 so I think a third equation is necessary for that

Comment: Or would it be I1R1-I2R2=0?